# Should I include title of posters and presentations on CV?

Tags: cv

I'm a Ph.D. candidate in physical chemistry. I have 13 posters and presentations on my CV, with a couple more upcoming. Right now, they each are listed as a bullet point on one line, in a format like this:

- `Northwest Regional Meeting (NORM) of the ACS             Oral presentation, Jun. 2019`
- `National Meeting of the American Chemical Society           Poster session, Apr. 2017`

Does this look ok? Specifically, should I include the titles of the presentations? I have seen titles on some CVs but I am worried about adding any unnecessary volume to my CV since it is currently at a tight 4 pages.

Aside from my specific question, I would welcome any other feedback about this format.

Comment: Addendum: I noticed after submitting my question that the lines were wrapped. The "Poster session, Apr. 2017" portion in my CV is right-justified and on the same line as the rest of the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't list titles, especially if it takes an extra line to do so. Titles of papers/preprints are important but I don't think presentation titles are - presumably you were talking about something from your list of papers, and I can't see why it would matter exactly what. My impression (though this could be field dependent, and I am not in your field) is that most people don't include titles, particularly if they have more than three or four presentations.

I would use a numbered list rather than bullet points, though - if someone cares about the number of presentations, you may as well make it easy for them.

Answer (score 1):

What is in the CV is up to you, but I'd suggest listing the titles. As it is, it isn't informative to the reader.

I'd also suggest, since you are worried about length, to separate these out into a section and list it at (near?) the end so that a reader can stop when they like but see more important things (papers) if they come earlier.

Presentations seem to me to be at least a bit more important than posters (field dependent).